# Role-Based Authentication in Next.js (v13.4) - How to Handle Dynamic Routes?

Tags: next.js, next-router

I'm relatively new to Next.js (using version 13.4), and I'm currently working on implementing role-based authentication in my Next.js application. I've made progress with handling static page routes using a Higher-Order Component (HOC), but I'm facing a challenge when it comes to dynamic routes.

**Here's what I've accomplished so far:**

**Static Routes:** I've created a route.ts file within my application, which contains all the static routing paths based on the user's role. This file is then imported into my Higher-Order Component (HOC), and it effectively manages access permissions for static routing pages based on user roles.

**Dynamic Routes:** The challenge I'm facing is how to handle dynamic routes. I couldn't include dynamic paths in my route.ts file because I'm not sure what dynamic routes will look like in advance. Consequently, I'm stuck when it comes to handling dynamic routes in the context of role-based authentication.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to handle dynamic routes in a role-based authentication setup in Next.js, especially in version 13.4. If you've encountered a similar situation or have a recommended approach, please share your knowledge—it would be incredibly valuable. Thank you!

`route.ts`

```
interface HeaderNavItem {
  name: string;
  path: string;
}

interface Role {
  path: string[];
}

interface Roles {
  [key: string]: Role; // different key name
}

const roles: Roles = {
  superAdmin: {
    path: ["/", "/admin", "/superadmin", "/user"],
  },
  admin: {
    path: ["/", "/admin", "/user", "/admin/test"],
  },
  user: {
    path: ["/", "/user"],
  },
};

export default roles;
```

`Higher-Order-Component`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter, usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import roles from "@/utils/rout"; 
import { isLoginReducer } from "@/redux/features/authSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "@/components/elements/Loader";

const UseRoleHook = (Component: any) => {
  return function ProtectedRoute() {
    // Get user role and login status from Redux store
    const { role, isLogin } = useSelector(
      (state: { authPersistedReducer: { role: string; isLogin: boolean } }) =>
        state.authPersistedReducer
    );

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
      // Check if the user is not logged in
      if (!isLogin) {
        // If the role is "admin", "superAdmin", or "user", set login status to true and redirect to the home page
        if (role === "admin" || role === "superAdmin" || role === "user") {
          dispatch(isLoginReducer(true)); // Dispatch the action to update the login state
          router.push("/");
        } else {
          router.push("/login"); // Redirect the user to the login page if the role is not recognized
        }
      } else {
        // If the user is logged in
        // Check if the current pathname is allowed for the user's role
        if (!roles[role]?.path.includes(pathname)) {
          // If not allowed, throw an error indicating "Permission Denied"
          throw new Error("Permission Denied");
        } else {
          // If allowed, redirect the user to the current pathname
          router.push(pathname);
        }
      }
    }, [isLogin, role, pathname]);

    if (!roles[role]?.path.includes(pathname)) {
      // If not, return a loading spinner using the Loader component while the correct route is loaded
      return (
        // Or display a loading spinner or message
        <div className="w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
          <Loader />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return <Component />;
  };
};

export default UseRoleHook;
```